# Sales Bar Chart

Tags: c++

this is a program that calculates sales for 5 stores,
and I am supposed to create a program that shows each of it's earning for today.
This is what I have so far:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
//stores 1-5 variables
int store1; int store2; int store3; int store4; int store5;
// calculations
int sale1; int sale2; int sale3; int sale4; int sale5;

int counter;



cout << "Please enter today's sales for store 1: " ;
cin  >> store1;
cout << "Please enter today's sales for store 2: " ;
cin  >> store2;
cout << "Please enter today's sales for store 3: " ;
cin  >> store3;
cout << "Please enter today's sales for store 4: " ;
cin  >> store4;
cout << "Please enter today's sales for store 5: " ;
cin  >> store5;


cout << endl << "Sales Bar Chart";
cout << endl << "Each asterisks (*) respresents $100" << endl;

sale1 = sale1 / 100;
sale2 = sale2 / 100;
sale3 = sale3 / 100;
sale4 = sale4 / 100;
sale5 = sale5 / 100;

cout << "Store 1: ";
    for ( counter = 0; counter < sale1; counter++)
            cout << '*';
    cout << endl << "Store 2: ";
    for ( counter = 0; counter < sale2; counter++)
            cout << '*';
    cout << endl << "Store 3: ";
    for ( counter = 0; counter < sale3; counter++)
            cout << '*';
    cout << endl << "Store 4: ";
    for ( counter = 0; counter < sale4; counter++)
            cout << '*';
    cout << endl << "Store 5: ";
    for ( counter = 0; counter < sale5; counter++)
            cout << '*';


    cin.get();
    cin.get();
```

My problem is that the program is suppose to output the sales like this

```
Enter today's sales for store 1 : 100
Enter today's sales for store 2 : 200
Enter today's sales for store 3 : 300
Enter today's sales for store 4 : 400
Enter today's sales for store 5 : 500
```

sales bar chart
each * represents $100
Store 1:*
Store 2:*
Store 3:*
Store 4:*
Store 5:*

however, my input just puts numerous amounts of asterisks like this
http://tinypic.com/view.php?pic=9h0wh2&s=8#.VHJjb4vF-QM
I have no idea what I did wrong.

Comment: *"I have no idea what I did"* is not a very well-researched programming question.

Comment: Are you reading the compiler warnings that you get when compiling this code?  Have you maybe disabled compiler warnings?  You can get assistance with typos like yours automatically.

Comment: Good point. I'll keep that in mind next time, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically the problem here is just a typo/wrong name.

```
cout << "Please enter today's sales for store 1: " ;
cin  >> store1;
```

You input into `store1` but then you don't use it when you do your calculation because you have:

```
sale1 = sale1 / 100;
        ^^^^^
        oops?
```

You really should compile your code with all warnings enabled and pay attention to them. In this case you would most likely have received warnings about using variables that were not initialized. Get in the habit of doing this as it will help you a lot in the future.

Comment: @LocoDoco, glad it helped. Also, if answers solve your problem on this site you might like to mark the answer as accepted by clicking the checkmark next to the question. This is entirely optional.